# How much should my cleric charge in a shop?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, healing

My DM is allowing PCs during downtime to find work. Thinking that my character is a cleric with the life domain might net him more during the downtime that just as a common laborer. I haven't been able to find anything 5E specific about running a magic shop of healing, making healing potions, how much to charge, etc.

I have seen older rule sets that basically charge xGP per level of spell +/- ingredients. And since the DMG isn't available yet, I can't look there.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can earn enough money to support a comfortable lifestyle. You might be able to swing wealthy with the right conversation with your DM.

Basically the way that downtime activities work in 5e is as described on pg 187 of the PHB. What it boils down to is as follows:

- practice profession (unaffiliated) - Modest lifestyle
- practice profession (affiliated) - comfortable
- practice perform skill - wealthy

So what you'd want to argue is that using your spell casting as a service in a shop would *at least* be equivalent to an affiliated profession and thus net you enough for a comfortable lifestyle. If you really wanted to push it, you might be able to talk your DM into a wealthy lifestyle.

If you don't want to settle for the professional abstraction, you *might* take your cues from page 159, the spell casting services section. This indicates that a first or second level spell may be cast by an NPC caster from between 10-50 gp.

Here's the thing with that though, what the lifestyle/profession numbers capture that the spell casting services don't (and why I'll use lifestyle/profession in my games) is the economic forces at play. YOu don't know *how often* someone in the general populace is going to need a first or second level spell cast, and thus you don't know when you'll earn gold and when you won't. This puts a lot on the DM to determine when it is otherwise properly abstracted by the lifestyle mechanic.

Comment: You could always use the Shop tables in the DMG to roll for "finding a buyer" or similar. This would also include selling potions (aka magic items).

Comment: You might also be able to leverage your position in a religious hierarchy (if applicable) to perform weddings, funerals, and other religious rites.

Answer (score 2):

If you are a cleric, and you wish to earn some coin during down time as the rest of your party is doing various things, there are two reasons to provide services at a discount from the prices listed in the books as published.

1. To get the trade.  (Economics at work)
2. To evangelize.  Any cleric has at least some calling to draw people to their belief.  If your "lesser restoration" service is at a lower price than at the local temple of "the deity that's happening now" then your ability to spread your particular word/belief is hopefully enhanced.
   WARNING:
   Don't forget to tithe/contribute a portion of what you earn using your deity's blessings back to your local chapel or temple.  Remember where your powers came from: your deity.

The above is a "spirit of the rules" point based on playing D & D since it came out.