# How much can my cleric player earn per day?

Tags: dnd-5e

One of my players is a lvl 4 cleric of Lathander, who works in a temple in the city of Laelith as an acolyte. He wants to sell his spells at the temple to gain 5gp/day (+the shelter/food/expense, so you add something 1-2gp/day).

He based his price on [this post](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109343/how-much-should-npcs-charge-for-spells-cast-as-services-to-pcs) with a discount. At first I said no, because, based on the rulebook, 5gp/day is a rich lifestyle and for someone who works as an acolyte in a temple of a Good god, I find this a bit paradoxical.

He's arguing the spell are sold for a fraction of their value and it's for a good cause (he wants to send some of this money to his hometown).

I've done some research and am struggling to find good data on what a player could earn per day by selling spell in this context. I though of giving him something like 2gp/day (for his work at the temple, based on the "job" section) + a bonus when he's asked for a spell from the temple.

What your thoughts on the subject?

Comment: Greetings. Welcome to RPGSE.  The way that you have presented your problem opens the door for opinion based answers.  I think you'll get the kind of input you'd like from a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/22566).  [Tour], [ask] and [answer] provide some guidance on our limitations in scope in this Q&A format.  There really isn't "one most correct answer" to your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How much should my cleric charge in a shop?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49414/how-much-should-my-cleric-charge-in-a-shop)

Comment: Restating your question, looking for rules-based guidance instead of "thoughts", will probably get this question reopened.

Comment: @MikeQ Thanks. Look like I didn't used the right term for my research.

Comment: He's a D&D character. Why is he working a day job instead of adventuring?

Comment: @MarkWells I get where you're coming from, but [Practicing a Profession](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#PracticingaProfession) is a standard downtime option. Some adventurers only adventure part-time!

Comment: I would think that casting Cleric spells while working the day job at the temple would be accounted for in their earning enough to support a comfortable lifestyle-- no bonus payments, it's just part of the job. You won't get a job making Big Macs at McDonald's earning an hourly wage and then also get bonus pay for each Big Mac you make.